# Unique Queue Overflow Condition (having less elements than its size)

Tags: data-structures, queue

Got this competitive question:

```
Which of the following data structure may give overflow error, even though the current number of elements in it is less than its size?

a. Stack 

b. Circular queue 

c. Simple queue                        

d. None of the above
```

I tried to Google the answer for a proper explanation however several sources marked (c) and (b) as answers which confused me even more. What's the explanation and the proper answer? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems somewhat strange because if you implement any of these structures correctly, there will be no such premature overflow.

With that in mind, Circular queue does seem like the most sensible answer. Here's why:

*Note: In my explanation, the queue adds to* `back` *and removes from* `front`

After certain number of insertions/deletions, the pointers to `front` and `back` in the circular queue (implemented as an array) may be on either side of each other.

[image: circular queue]

This means that when adding elements to this queue, on top of standard checks, we also have to be aware of the **relative position** of the `front` and `back` pointers.

In the second picture above we have to realize that adding to `back` has to add to the beginning of the array now, since `back` is at the end of the array. In other words, adding elements has to "***circle around***". If we don't implement this check properly, we would end up with an overflow even though there's still room in the queue.

Comment: I guessed the same. Thanks mate.

Comment: You're welcome. Its a strange question, wouldn't really judge somebody by it since it can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Ans is (c)simple queue.we are assuming that elements can be inserted using rear and can be deleted using front pointer..And also assume that maximum size of queue is 10(eg.) ....Now if the rear is point at index no 9...Means there are total 10 elements in queue. And the position of front is 0 index .Now if we remove elements from other end  then the value of  front become 1 .........here, actually queue is not full bcz index 0 is empty... But due to the condition of the rear pointer which is max-1 the output shows that queue is full....And the sol of that is implemented in circular queue.